# Variadic templates: unfold arguments in groups

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I have a function that takes two arguments:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void foo(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
{ std::cout << arg1 << " + " << arg2 << '\n'; }
```

And a variadic one that should forward its arguments in pairs :

```
template <typename... Args>
void bar(Args&&... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) % 2 == 0);

    ( foo( std::forward<Args>(args), std::forward<Args>(args) ), ... );
    // ^ Sends each argument twice, not in pairs
}
```

I would want `bar(1,2,3,4)` to call `foo(1,2)` and `foo(3,4)`

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: It's dangerous to forward the same args twice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can accomplish it with overloads.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void bar(T1&& arg1, T2&& arg2) {
    foo( std::forward<T1>(arg1), std::forward<T2>(arg2) ); // (until) sends (the last) two arguments to foo
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Args>
void bar(T1&& arg1, T2&& arg2, Args&&... args) {
    foo( std::forward<T1>(arg1), std::forward<T2>(arg2) ); // sends the 1st two arguments to foo
    bar( std::forward<Args>(args)... );                    // call bar with remaining elements recursively
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/56PiEvs3M4mc7xbE)

---

<sup>Note that with the minimum snippet above when calling `bar` with 0 or odd arguments you'll get *no matching function* error. If you want more clear compilation message with `static_assert` you can start from this [snippet](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oLrxGIgaNAXtgRyj).</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Simple recursion using `if constexpr`:

```
// print as many pairs as we can
template<class T, class U, class... Args>
void foo(T t, U u, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << t << " + " << u << "\n";
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Args) > 0 && sizeof...(Args) % 2 == 0)
        foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class... Args>
void bar(Args&&... args)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) % 2 == 0);
    foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Call it like so:

```
bar(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0YDGmYj0ZdN0OUTM)

I would say that [songyanyao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59018650/27678) is pretty canonical pre-C++17. Afterwards, [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) has allowed us to move logic into the bodies of our functions instead of using overloading tricks.

Comment: songyanyao's version is pretty easy to extend, such that it also takes the function it is applying as an argument. In my opinion this is pretty nice, since it allows us to apply this pattern multiple times without having to write the logic everytime. Is there a version of your answer that allows the same?

Comment: @n314159: Something like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j44PafdmOkKIWGUB)?

Comment: Exactly! Thank you. Personally I prefer this, since (additionally to what I already said) it seperates the apply-logic from the function it is applied to.

Answer (score 2):

C++17 generalization for `n`-ary functors:

```
namespace impl
{
    template<std::size_t k, class Fn, class Tuple, std::size_t... js>
    void unfold_nk(Fn fn, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<js...>) {
        fn(std::get<k + js>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...);
    }

    template<std::size_t n, class Fn, class Tuple, std::size_t... is>
    void unfold_n(Fn fn, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<is...>) {
        (unfold_nk<n * is>(fn, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), 
            std::make_index_sequence<n>{}), ...);
    }
}

template<std::size_t n, class Fn, typename... Args>
void unfold(Fn fn, Args&&... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) % n == 0);
    impl::unfold_n<n>(fn, std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...), 
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) / n>{});
}

int main() {
    auto fn = [](auto... args) { 
        (std::cout << ... << args) << ' ';
    };

    unfold<2>(fn, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);   // Output: 12 34 56
    unfold<3>(fn, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);   // Output: 123 456
}
```